# Bootstrap 4 Navbar toggle not display in iPad

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I use  `Bootstrap 4 beta`  my Navbar  header is not perfect in iPad, but small devices its working perfect, how to fix my issue, please help me to fix that issue
 you can understand my issue, please look working snippet

Thanks

```html
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    
    
    <header>
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">School-PROJECT</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler d-lg-none" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
    
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
              <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">DASHBOARD<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">BOOKING</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">ROOMS</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">HOTEL MANAGER</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">PETTY CASH</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">CASH MANAGEMENT</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </header>
    <!--Navbar--------------------------------------------------------------------->
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `navbar-expand-md` to `navbar-expand-lg` because of the large no of menu items, there is some spacing and alignment issue is coming in that resolution.

```html
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    
    
    <header>
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">School-PROJECT</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler d-lg-none" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
    
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
              <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">DASHBOARD<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">BOOKING</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">ROOMS</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">HOTEL MANAGER</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">PETTY CASH</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">CASH MANAGEMENT</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </header>
    <!--Navbar--------------------------------------------------------------------->
```